# Does sklearnex (sklearn-intel-extension) really support linear regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gpu, intel

I'm trying to use [sklearnex/scikit-learn-intelex](https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/) for GPU accelaration. This is my code, learnt from '[Patching several algorithms:](https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/quick-start.html)':

```
try:
    from sklearnex import patch_sklearn
    patch_sklearn()
except:
    pass
patch_sklearn(['PCA','LinearRegression'])
```

[Apparently](https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/algorithms.html) the package suppports linear regression. However, it returns the following error on my machine:

```
> Intel(R) Extension for Scikit-learn* enabled (https://github.com/intel/scikit-learn-intelex)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/path/tmp_test.py", line 16, in <module>
> patch_sklearn(['PCA','LinearRegression'])
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearnex/dispatcher.py", line 177, in patch_sklearn
> patch_sklearn_orig(algorithm, verbose=False, deprecation=False,
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daal4py/sklearn/monkeypatch/dispatcher.py", line 127, in enable
> do_patch(name, get_map)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daal4py/sklearn/monkeypatch/dispatcher.py", line 111, in do_patch
> raise ValueError("Has no patch for: " + name)
> ValueError: Has no patch for: LinearRegression
```

What's wrong with my code? The package [supports](https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/algorithms.html) linear regression and I did exactly [the way in the example](https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/quick-start.html)

When I patch `PCA` only, the algo works normaly. I'm using [the latest version of this package.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhtDH.png). The original sklearn works fine if I don't import sklearnex.

Comment: Just to double check in case, did you import scikit-learn after these lines? Otherwise, the patching will not affect the original scikit-learn estimators as stated in the docs.

You can also try to only do `patch_sklearn()`, and patch everything and see if it works.

Comment: @Jose I did import `sklearn` after the PCA patch. The Error comes from line `patch_sklearn(['PCA','LinearRegression'])`. Moreover, `patch_sklearn(['PCA'])` is fine, but `patch_sklearn(['LinearRegression'])` results in error.

Comment: you are right, maybe try to only do `patch_sklearn()`, and patch everything and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix for code itself - this would work, but this is not clear naming that would be fixed - https://github.com/intel/scikit-learn-intelex/pull/1343

patch_sklearn(['PCA','Linear'])

patch_sklearn() would affect only your CPU code - i.e. regular scikit code.

In case of GPU there is no notion of GPU support in scikit-learn itself.

To run on GPU (note: only Intel GPUs support ) you ether have to use explicit definition with config_context or pass GPU data(dpctl tensor) to algorithm
https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/oneapi-gpu.html

Comment: You mentioned Intel GPU. Does it mean that the package has no impact on Nvidia RTX4090 GPU?  It seems that the link [DPC++ System](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/system-requirements/intel-oneapi-dpcpp-system-requirements.html) indeed only mentions Intel GPU.

Comment: Yes, the primary objective is to support Intel GPUs. There is some path toward non Intel GPUs support as kernels written in SYCL which is portable and there is SYCL  runtime implementation for NVidia but this would require some engineering work on integration and validation.